# Set an error if value1 is greater than value2

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to check if the value of one text field is greater than the other. If so, an error should be set.

This is what I have tried out:

```
if (this.min.nativeElement.value > this.max.nativeElement.value) {
  this.primaryFormGroup.controls.max.setErrors({
    minIsGreaterThanMax: true
  })
}
```

This is how I try to check if the error is set:

```
<span *ngIf="this.primaryFormGroup.min.hasError('minIsGreaterThanMax')">Min is greater than max</span>
```

I must be doing something wrong, since my error message never appears.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erpc61?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  <form [formGroup]="primaryFormGroup">
  <input type="number" formControlName="min" #min>
  <input type="number" formControlName="max" #max>
  <span *ngIf="this.primaryFormGroup.get('min').errors?.minIsGreaterThanMax">Min is greater than max</span>
  </form>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
```

On your ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {


  this.primaryFormGroup.get('min').valueChanges
   .subscribe(value => {
        const max = this.primaryFormGroup.get('max').value

        if (value > max) {
          this.primaryFormGroup.get('min').setErrors({
            'minIsGreaterThanMax': true
          })
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't see any changes reflected in your template is because currently in the code, the comparison is done directly against the template once.

To see it update dynamically, you can subscribe to the form value changes, perform the comparison, and set the error if necesasry. This also means we need to unsubscribe in `onDestroy` to prevent any memory leaks.

```js
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  <form [formGroup]="primaryFormGroup">
    <input type="number" formControlName="min">
    <input type="number" formControlName="max">
  </form>
  <span *ngIf="primaryFormGroup?.controls?.max?.errors?.minIsGreaterThanMax">Min is greater than max</span>
  <!-- value changes demo -->
  <pre>{{primaryFormGroup.valueChanges | async | json}}</pre>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnDestroy  {
  @Input() name
  primaryFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    min: 0,
    max: 0
  });

private subs: Subscription[] = []; 

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // cleanup
  this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
}

ngOnInit() {
  const checkFormForErrorsSub = this.primaryFormGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
    tap(({min,max}) => {
      if (min > max) {
        this.primaryFormGroup.controls.max.setErrors({ minIsGreaterThanMax: true })
      }
    })
  ).subscribe();

  this.subs.push(checkFormForErrorsSub);
}

}
```

Another way to perform validation is via a custom validator, resources below:
Official Docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators
Article: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html